# Nhibernate critera with subquery

Tags: c#, sql, hibernate, nhibernate

I would like help to create this query in nhibernate using critera api (removed unnecessary parts from the sql):

```
SELECT this_.ID as ID120_1 FROM SS10_FOLDER this_ 
where this_.id in (select folderacce1_.resource_id from SS10_FOLDER_ACCESS folderacce1_ WHERE folderacce1_.GROUP_ID in (6174,6155));
```

My current solution uses "inner join" but I want to avoid it and use the "in select" as in the sql above. "groupIds" is a list of ids in c#.

```
var critiera = _session.CreateCriteria<H>();
criteria.CreateCriteria("Access", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin).Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.In("Group.Id", groupIds));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

```
DetachedCriteria subQuery = DetachedCriteria.For<A>("Access")
                .Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.In("Access.Group.Id", SmartContext.Current.GetGroupIds(Session).ToList())).SetProjection(Projections.Property("Access.Resource.Id"));

criteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", subQuery));
```